# Set servlet initialization parameters in WebSphere Liberty

Tags: servlets, websphere-liberty

I have been supplied a WAR that contains a servlet.  In the source of that servlet there are default initialization parameters ... for example:

`@WebInitParam(
   name        = "proxyHttpsPort", 
   value       = "9445", 
   description = "EPS Proxy HTTPS port"
),`

My puzzle is how to over-ride these defaults in my local WebSphere Liberty environment.  Does anyone know how to set the values of the initialization parameters such that when the servlet is loaded/started, my locally supplied values will be used rather than the default values baked into the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we define a Servlet, we can do so through Java annotation.  For example:

`@WebServlet`

We can also define initialization parameters:

`@WebInitParam(name="name", value="value")`

The notion behind an initialization parameter is to provide run-time configuration parameter that may be distinct by location where the solution is deployed.  For example, on one system, an initialization parameter may have:

`name="passwordFile", value="/etc/mypasswords.txt"`

while on a different system, we may have:

`name="passwordFile", value="/tmp/test_passwords.txt"`

We don't want to hard-code these values in our applications but, instead, provide a default value that can be over-ridden at run-time.

When we build a Dynamic Web App for deployment on Java EE, we can define the servlet exclusively through annotations in code and this is the preferred style these days.   However, before annotations, one defined the characteristics of a dynamic web project (including its servlets) through an XML file called web.xml.  Within this file, one could supply a large set of configuration parameters including servlets and, for a servlet, the initialization parameters.

It appears that the web.xml technique is still available to us and can be used in conjunction with the Java annotations.  What this means is that we can declare our Servlet and initialization parameters via annotations and at the same time, create a web.xml file.  Where a value is found through annotation and there is no corresponding web.xml value, then the annotation will be used.  However, if both an annotation and the same web.xml definition are present, then the web.xml definition will be the one actually used.  Since the web.xml is an "exposed" configuration file, at deployment, we can edit web.xml to set the desired value for anything we wish to over-ride … including initialization parameters.